Need to do custom clustering in mapbox for react-native
I have use the mapbox GL. How can I create custom cluster with different color and how can I display the different color markers? And how can set the zoom level particular state wise? When I am click on the cluster circle, then zoom in to the particular city.
<MapboxGL.ShapeSource
                  id="circleSource"
                  shape={tempMapGeoJason}
                  cluster={true}
                  clusterRadius={50}
                  clusterMaxZoom={10}
                  // onPress={onCirclePress}
                  onPress={handleCirclePress}>
                  <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
                    id="pointCount"
                    style={{
                      textColor: 'white',
                      textField: '{point_count}',
                      textSize: 14,
                      textPitchAlignment: 'map',
                    }}
                  />
                  <MapboxGL.CircleLayer
                    id="clusteredPoints"
                    belowLayerID="pointCount"
                    filter={['has', 'point_count']}
                    style={{
                      circleRadius: [
                        'step',
                        ['get', 'point_count'],
                        20,
                        100,
                        40,
                        750,
                        50,
                      ],
                      circleColor: [
                        'step',
                        ['get', 'point_count'],
                        'green',
                        5,
                        'green',
                        10,
                        'green',
                      ],


                      // circleOpacity: 0.7,
                    }}
                  />
                  <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
                    id={farmLocations}
                    filter={['!', ['has', 'point_count']]}
                    style={{
                      iconImage: imagePath.mapMarkerGrey,
                      iconSize: 0.8,
                      iconAllowOverlap: true,
                    }}
                  />
                </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>

To set cluster state wise and to set marker with different color
